# How to calculate total from Hashmap Java

Tags: java, count, hashmap

I have this current output:

```
First clusters: [[1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 1, 1]]  

0 : 4, Probability: 0.8 , logVal: -0.2575424759098898
1 : 1, Probability: 0.2 , logVal: -0.46438561897747244

0 : 3, Probability: 0.6 , logVal: -0.44217935649972373
1 : 2, Probability: 0.4 , logVal: -0.5287712379549449

0 : 5, Probability: 1.0 , logVal: 0.0

0 : 4, Probability: 0.8 , logVal: -0.2575424759098898
1 : 1, Probability: 0.2 , logVal: -0.46438561897747244

0 : 3, Probability: 0.6 , logVal: -0.44217935649972373
1 : 2, Probability: 0.4 , logVal: -0.5287712379549449
```

then for each logVal I would like to total them for example:
The first data:

```
0 : 4, Probability: 0.8 , logVal: -0.2575424759098898  
1 : 1, Probability: 0.2 , logVal: -0.46438561897747244  

total[0] = (-0.2575424759098898) + (-0.46438561897747244)
```

Next, for 2nd data:

```
0 : 3, Probability: 0.6 , logVal: -0.44217935649972373  
1 : 2, Probability: 0.4 , logVal: -0.5287712379549449

total[1] = (-0.44217935649972373) + (-0.5287712379549449)
```

and so on until the last data. But I'm not sure how to get the index of each data so each data logVal can be total up together using HashMap.

This is my code so far:

```
public static void printCount(HashMap<String, Integer> countMap, int length) {
    double logVal = 0.0, entropy = 0.0, probability = 0.0;

    Set<String> keySet = countMap.keySet();

    for (String bit : keySet) {
        //System.out.println(bit + " : " + countMap.get(bit));

        probability = (double)countMap.get(bit)/length;

        logVal = (probability*(Math.log(probability)/Math.log(2)));

        System.out.println(bit + " : " + countMap.get(bit) + ", Probability: " + probability + " , logVal: " + logVal);

        total = logVal + logVal;

        System.out.println("Total = " + total);

    }

    System.out.println();

}
```

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: to total up the logVal for each data. I couldn't get the correct total because no index in HashMap. I got like this:

0 : 1, Probability: 0.3333333333333333 , logVal: -0.5283208335737187
Total = -1.0566416671474375
1 : 2, Probability: 0.6666666666666666 , logVal: -0.38997500048077083
Total = -0.7799500009615417

but I need the logVal for bit 0 to add up with logVal for bit 1

Comment: Your data seems to be 2-dimensional and depending on the index (according to your question) so using (only) a map might not be the best choice. Why not a list or dedicated objects or if you really want a list of lists or even a 2d array?

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
total = logVal + logVal;
System.out.println("Total = " + total);
```

by

```
String totalString = "(" + logVal + ") + (" + logVal ")";
System.out.println("Total = " + totalString);
```

If you need to store it (you wrote `total[0] = ...` just use a `String[] totals`.